# Cannot associate a custom SharePoint Workflow with a Content Type in SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, content-type

To preface, I am working with SharePoint Server 2010 Beta 2, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC.

I have built a custom Content Type based on the Item type with a few custom site columns.  I also have built a custom Sequential Workflow using Visual Studio 2010.  This is a relatively simple workflow that creates a task, waits for the task to complete, sets the workflow to complete.  I am able to deploy this workflow to the site collection through VS 2010 deploy (which is pretty nice, btw).  The problem I have is that when I try to associate the custom Content Type with my custom workflow, that workflow is not listed in the workflow templates to choose from.  There are only the OOTB SharePoint workflows to choose.  The kicker is that if I create a list and associate a workflow to that list, my custom workflow **is** in the workflow template list.  This makes sense since at the start of building a custom workflow in VS2010, one of the first questions is whether the workflow is a Site or a List workflow and I selected List.  Is the issue that List workflows are not allowed to be associated with Content Types?!?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your workflow's elements.xml, look for AssociationCategories and change it to ContentType like so:

```
<AssociationCategories>ContentType</AssociationCategories>
```

Big thanks to my co-worker, Yves for pointing this out :)